# Select Word after specific word in Field

Tags: mysql

I have a string field, FieldS, that can be 2-10 words long. I can easily find all fields that contain word 'X' but what I am looking for is to extract all unique word pairs with 'X NextWord'. Clearly I can do

```
Select FieldS from Table1 where FieldS like '% X %'
```

and I'm thinking somehow there is a `substring_index` involved here but I can't construct if after several tries so thought perhaps there is a more relevant function I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `substring_index()` -- twice.

Here is one way:

```
select concat(X, ' ',
              substring_index(substring_index(field5, 'X', -1), ' ', 1)
             )
```

Notes:

- This assumes that 'X' only occurs once in the string.  Or, more accurately, it uses the last occurrence of `'X'` in the field.
- This assumes that the only word break character is space.

EDIT:

If you are concerned about the spaces around the `X` you can use:

```
select concat(X, ' ',
              substring_index(substring_index(concat(' ', field5, ' '), ' X ', -1), ' ', 1)
             )
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, what would happen if `X` is inside another word as last character? something like `TRIPLEX NextWord` would this answer cover it?

Comment: @JorgeCampos . . . I revised the answer.